# Similar to IAR __stackless for GCC

Tags: c, gcc, stack, push, iar

Is there a function attribute in GCC which acts as __stackless in IAR?

I've been looking for it and didn't find anything...

Thanks in advance
Regards,

Victor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a combination of `naked` and `noreturn`.

`__attribute__((naked,noreturn,optimize("-O3")))`

```
extern int *x;

void __attribute__((naked,noreturn,optimize("-O3"))) foo(int a, int b)
{
    for(int c = a; c < b; c++)
    {
        x[c] = c * a;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xf9YKa

Comment: Does IAR __stackless or GCC naked guarantee that the stack *won’t be used*? The documentation of __stackless implies that such a function can be called without a working stack, but naked makes no such guarantee.

Comment: @nneonneo there is no such a option in gcc so I wrote "I would". BTW __stackless is almost not used in ARM development (I personally do not see any use). For the more usage cases this combination of attributes will be enough

Comment: @nneonneo I tested some more complicated cases and unless you pass too many arguments or define automatic `volatile` variables or large data structures inside this function it does not use stack. BTW IAR in the same border cases emits the stack related code so it also does not guarantee it (it can be abused). But this kind of functions are used in a very specific circumstances and code should use only data (variables) which will fit in registers.

Comment: Not that anybody's still looking, but I needed __stackless for my `__low_level_init()` function to set up RAM mapping before the stack could be accessed by the ROM.   Otherwise the compiler generated `push` instructions to the stack before it was available